# What is this bush/shrub that has thorns?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

It also produces some type of fruit late summer / early fall.

[[image: ]]
[[image: ]]
[[image: ]]
[[image: ]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's just beginning to bloom, but later on, if it's covered with showy dark pink or coral-colored flowers, it's a Flowering quince, or Chaenomeles.

Answer (score 1):

Chaenomeles speciosa 'Apple Blossom' A quince with pinkish white blossoms.  This is just an example as there is no easy way to tell exactly which quince you've got.  Lorel is correct and was firstus!